# Not understanding IntentFilters

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am trying to copy a binary file (my own bespoke content, not a standard) from Google Drive to my app using the 'Send a Copy' menu item in Google Drive.

I had a look at the intent that Google Drive sends using Intent Intercept, and it basically is

- ACTION - android.intent.action.SEND
- DATA - null
- MIME - application/octet-stream
- URI - intent:#intent;action=android.intent.action.SEND;type=application/octet-stream;launchFlags=0x1b080000;end
- FLAGS - FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET 
  FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND
- Extras - 1 Class: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri Key: android.intent.extra.STREAM Value: content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3Dy1Gjnka2NiGyk8sKV0CwRjnjL3WimTTirLdLn58FBZ7yVAJ2MPJNL_ZYQFzzl0a3pi0bnikAy29Y%0AcprYV_o8bxcPbb8r0Vv_wfq89BjBp1nQHOPUT8CiHQEzPwVwRhvByYmijg%3D%3D%0A

The intent filter in my app's relevant activity is:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    </intent-filter>
```

and after some messing around it does now show up in the 'Send file with' list in Google Drive.

If I select my app as the target, it turns up in the onCreate() of the relevant activity, I can get the intent OK with getIntent(), but getData() - which is what I used to use with ACTION_VIEW intents from other places - returns null, probably not surprising as Data is listed as null in the intent above.

What I am not at all sure - with my limited knowledge and having read the 'Receiving simple data from other apps' documentation - is what to do next. How do I get access to the file data so I can copy it?

The next question, assuming I do succeed at that (with helpful answers), if I want to send multiple files at once from Google Drive, it looks to me that it will then use the SEND_MULTIPLE intent, so how would I access each files data then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get access to the file data so I can copy it?

A `Uri` pointing to the shared content is in `EXTRA_STREAM`. Call `getParcelableExtra()` on the `Intent` to retrieve it. You can then use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the content identified by that `Uri`.

How to obtain the value of the extra is covered by [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive#handling-content).

> it will then use the SEND_MULTIPLE intent, so how would I access each files data then?

`EXTRA_STREAM` will now be a list of `Uri` values. Call `getParcelableArrayListExtra()` on the `Intent` to retrieve it. You can then iterate over that list and use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get the content identified by the `Uri`.

As before, how to obtain the value the extra is covered by [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive#handling-content).